# flatten directory hierarchy for multiple root directories using Windows command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this structure:

```
Folder Root
   Folder A
      Folder 1
          file1.jpg
          file2.jpg
      Folder 2
          file3.jpg
   Folder B       
      Folder 1
         file4.jpg
   Folder C
       Folder 1
          file5.jpg
          file6.jpg
          file7.jpg
          file8.jpg
       Folder 2
           file9.jpg
           file10.jpg
```

Now I want all the files in the subfolder of A to be in A, B in B and so on.
With this code:

```
for /r %f in (*) do move "%f"
```

I have to enter each folder (A, B, C) manually, this is not an option, I have hundreds of directories that require this operation.

Is there a way to run the command from the Folder Root and recursively scroll to A, B and C and move the files from their respective subfolders?

Comment: `file1.jpg` from `Folder 1` and `Folder 2` cannot coexist in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Test this on a copy of your folders.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "%%a\*.jpg" /b /s /a-d') do move "%%b" "%%a"
```

Comment: Didn't work. I removed the @echo off line from the .bat file to see the output, is this:

Comment: for /r %b in ("Folder1\*") do move "%b" "Folder 1"
for /r %b in ("Folder2\*") do move "%b" "Folder 2"

Comment: Did you run it as a batch file or paste it into the cmd prompt?

Comment: As a batch file; thanks anyway, i've foud a workaround. The problem was nesting the fors

Comment: @thx0125 
It was my code that was faulty. The edited code in my question works here when run in the Folder Root, but test it on copies of your data first.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. Nesting fors just won't gonna do it. My solution is as follows.

Create a file moveToRoot.bat with this code

```
for /r %%f in (*) do move "%%f"
```

the create a file moveToRootBase.bat with this code

```
for /D %%d in (*) do (
copy copiaARaiz.bat "%%d"
cd "%%d" 
copiaARaiz.bat 
del copiaARaiz.bat
cd..)
```

Execute moveToRootBase.bat from Folder Root and done!